# Visual studio 2013 Slow in editing razor files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2013

I just had installed VS2013. When I press <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> keys in a razor file editor which it is not pure html and has some razor codes VS 2013 slow down and permanently consume ~25% of CPU and everything is slow until I restart the VS.

I noticed that the problem only occurs when the razor document is reopened. If the document is already open when you open the Solution the problem doesn't occur.

I try many things but none of them fix the problem:

- Disabling **Resharper**
- Disabling **Productivity Power Tools 2013**
- Deselecting "**Rich client visual experience**" in the "**Options - Environment**"
- Disabling git plug-in or other Source Control: set **Current source control** plug-in to **None**

I test it in same machine in VS 2012 and everything was working normal.

---

**Edit:** I had tested different scenarios and finally I found out that the following lines cause the problem:

```razor
<ul>
    <li style="@(!User.IsInRole("men") ? "display: none" : "")">Menu1</li>
    <li style="@(!User.IsInRole("women") ? "display: none" : "")">Menu2</li>
</ul>
```

If I remove the `style="@(!User.IsInRole("men") ? "display: none" : "")"` the problem not occurs anymore. Any idea?

---

**Edit:** I had reported the problem to microsoft [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/861957/visual-studio-2013-slow-down-in-editing-razor-files-until-restart) please upvote for better & quick support.

Comment: More Info: All add-in's and extensions have been disabled. And used VS is update 1.

Comment: Have you tried engaging with Microsoft support?  This is the kind of thing they are there for.

Comment: Are you working on a local folder or is your project on a network share?

Comment: @martinoss It is in a local folder. I just create an empty MVC project and add a view `blabla.cshtml` and past the above codes. and the problem occurs.

Comment: What happens if you replace `User.IsInRole("women")` with something like `(1==1)`? (Intellisense issue?) / Also try to run devenv.exe with /safemode.

Comment: @martinoss Replacing with `style="@(1==1 ? "display: none" : "")"` but the problem is there. How should I run devenv.exe in _safemode_?

Comment: Are you on Update 1?  Update 2 is imminent and a RC is available to try

Comment: @SkyBlues87 Yes as I mentioned in my first comment, I'm using Update 1 and waiting Update 2 being released. Many people have problems with Update2 RC.

Comment: How about your hardware configuration

Comment: @tarzanbappa checked in three different PCs, I had the same problem.

Comment: I had a similar problem in VS 2010... It was the version of Re-Sharper I was using. I uninstalled it at it was fine after that.

Comment: @MrCheese I disabled it via `Options`->`Resharper`->`Suspend Now` but the problem still was occurring. I would uninstall it for double checking whether the Resharper is the source of issue.

Comment: This question shouldn't be on SU ? since it's about the software (IDE) not the code?

Comment: @MichelAyres I don't think so, cause there are ~35k questions about [`[visual-studio]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio), ~12k [`[netbeans]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbeans), ... in the SO.

Comment: @ImanMahmoudinasab just because SO is older and has more popularity. We should consider when to move to others websites from the network, where it's a better fit.

Comment: @MichelAyres as it is said http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic "if your question generally covers… **software tools commonly used by programmers** … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: How to run VS in safemode: Devenv.exe /SafeMode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in ticket sent to MS , It was a bug which solved in **Update 2 RTM** of VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Anti-virus on your system, i had a similar issue on VS2012 project which got resolved with disabling Anti-Virus (later configuration changes by Security team), funny enough i also had issue only with Razor files (McAfee was culprit in my case).

Comment: I don't have any antivirus in my PC.

Answer (score 0):

If using TFS I have found that switching over to a server workspace is significantly faster if you have persitent internet connectivity. Otherwise, I would do two things, check the event log for any warnings or errors, and also use the task manager or process explorer.